# Не читает код sql, в чем может быть проблема?

Tags: python, sql

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect('db/database.db') as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    query = ''' INSERT INTO expenses (id, name) VALUES(1, "коммуналка") '''
```

// все воспроизводит как текст. файл не создался.

```
    cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: Может, он создался не там, где вы его ищете? Внимательно перепроверьте текущий рабочий каталог

Comment: Мало информации, может базу данных создать?

Comment: Если OS - Linux ищите файл в корне проекта